# Error in fetching highscore from database in decreasing order

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have developed a Quiz based App in Android. Now the problem is occurring when i am trying to arrange the High Scores in Decreasing order. I am getting error `invalid LIMIT clauses:score DESC`. I have posted here my database class and the class from which I am trying to fetch high score in Decreasing order. Please help me in solving this error.

DBAdapter.java

```
public long addscore(String name, int score)
{

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_name, name); 
    values.put(KEY_score, score);

    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, values);
}
public Cursor getScore() throws SQLException 
{

    String order = KEY_score + " DESC ";
    /*return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, new String[] {KEY_scoreid, KEY_name,
            KEY_score}, null, null, null, null, order);*/
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE1, new String[] {
            KEY_scoreid, KEY_name,KEY_score },null, null,null,null, null,order);
    if (mCursor != null) 
    {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

Highscore.java

```
    try
    {
        db1=new DBAdapter(this);
        db1.open();
        c=db1.getScore();

        n1=c.getString(1);
        s1=c.getInt(2);
        n2=c.getString(1);
        s2=c.getInt(2);
        n3=c.getString(1);
        s3=c.getInt(2);
        n4=c.getString(1);
        s4=c.getInt(2);
        n5=c.getString(1);
        s5=c.getInt(2);

        name1.setText(n1);
        score1.setText(Integer.toString(s1));
        name2.setText(n2);
        score2.setText(Integer.toString(s2));
        name3.setText(n3);
        score3.setText(Integer.toString(s3));
        name4.setText(n4);
        score4.setText(Integer.toString(s4));
        name5.setText(n5);
        score5.setText(Integer.toString(s5));

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I need your help guys, Please help!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What error you are getting? Please post your logcat.

Comment: wrong parameter ... check documentation and tell us what is the 9th parameter in `query` method

Comment: @Selvin Please tell me where ?

Comment: where what? checking the docs? in the internet

Comment: @GrIsHu I am getting this exception `invalid LIMIT clauses:score DESC`

Comment: Try to remove the space after `DESC` in your `order` variable.

Comment: @Selvin I am not getting the solution on google thats why i am asking here

Comment: @GrIsHu Is there any thing wrong in parameter ?

Comment: @GrIsHu Removed spaces nothing happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out as below:

```
Cursor mCursor =db.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, new String[] {KEY_scoreid,KEY_name,KEY_score}, null, null, null, null, KEY_score + " DESC");
```

**EDITED:**

> ```
> if (cur.getCount() > 0)
>             {
>                 if (cur.moveToFirst())
>                 {
>                     do
>                     {
>                         id1 = cur.getInt(0);
>                         name = cur.getString(1);
>                        Contacts contact_list = new Contacts(id1, name);
>                         contact.add(contact_list);
>                     } 
>                     while (cur.moveToNext());
>                 }
>                 cur.deactivate();
>                 cur.close();
>                 cdb.close();
>             }
> ```

Where your `Contact` is as below:

```
public class Contacts
{
    private int Id;
    private String NAME;
    public int getId()
    {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }
    public String getNAME()
    {
        return NAME;
    }
    public void setNAME(String name)
    {
        NAME = name;
    }
     public Contacts(int id, String name)
    {
        super();
        this.Id = id;
        NAME = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting Error `no such column: scoreid: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT scoreid,name,score from scores ORDER BY score DESC`

Comment: Do have any field named `scoreid` in  your table ? check out.

Comment: Please Show your create table query.

Comment: `private static final String DATABASE_CREATE1 = "create table scores (scoreid integer primary key autoincrement,"
   + "name TEXT" + "score NUMERIC"
   + ");";`

Comment: I think there is some mistake in fetching the data from score table.

Comment: In your query you have defined your table name explicitly which is not in constant. And in your query you have used constant for your table name. I guess its problem of getting correct table.

Comment: If you think so lemme check it again

Comment: but now in my Logcat i m getting this `Bad request for field slot 0,2. numRows = 1, numColumns = 2`

Comment: Its showing that your table contains only 1 row and you are trying to access two. Try to access data considering the rows starting from 0 `c.getString(0); c.getString(1); c.getString(2);` this way.

Comment: This error is solved but now I am getting same name and score in all text view

Comment: This error is solved but now I am getting same name and score in all text view.

Comment: Means I am getting same name and score in my high score page.

Comment: That is because you have only fetched one record. To get all the records you need to go through all the records using for loop with the size of the cursor i.e. `for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)`.

Comment: You need to store the data in some array of string and then you will have to show it in textview.

Comment: You need to pass the value of `i` in your `c.getString(i); c.getString(i); c.getString(i);`

Comment: Do I have store names and scores in same array ?

Comment: I have to show only 5 names thats why i am trying to fetch it manually like this `c.getString(1);c.getString(2);` and so on till 5.

Comment: Yes you can create `ArrayList<Details>` in which you can create `Details` in your POJO class in that you can create getter and setter method and set the value in your for loop. You can not fetch the 5 name without loop. You will have to go through cursor one by one.

Comment: Actually my mind is messed up and not working this time so can you please provide me the code how to do this

Comment: thanks i am accepting your answer but i have taken two array instead to making this messy array list.

Answer (score 0):

query should be like that

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE1, new String[] {
            KEY_scoreid, KEY_name,KEY_score },null, null,null,null,KEY_score + " DESC",null);
```

Comment: Getting Error `no such column: scoreDESC: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT scoreid,name,score from scores ORDER BY scoreDESC`

Comment: hey pls check `highscore.java` class. Have I passed the parameters correctly ?